# id is missing in my R.java file when working with arcgis project

Tags: android, arcgis

I was developing arcgis project application by Android and everything was working properly until yesterday.whenever I create a new Android application project and check the R.java file **id** is there but when I create a new arcgis project for android the R.java is missing **id**.I don't think it's my adb b/c this happens for the arcgis project only.so can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have it import

   2.Synchronized file R.class

   3.Run android studio as administrator

   Or
   [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: i am using eclipse.so can any one helpme please